# Steam Game Badge Count False?

Tags: steam

I have 28 games in total but on my steam profile it shows that i only have 5. I have already gotten the badge for 5games but shouldn't it show the 25 games badge? All help is appreciated:) thanks

Answer (score 9):

Non-Steam, DLC and Free to play games do not count towards the game count on your profile, this could be why you are seeing a difference between games in your library and the number of games shown on your profile.

One example is Call of Duty which has a single and multiplayer game listed in the library but will only add one to your games count.

Comment: Adding to this, the way to check the correct amount of games is to go to your steam profile and looking at the "Games" counter on the right sidebar.

Comment: @aman207 Wouldn't that count F2P games as well?